# Ajax.oncomplete escaping the singlequote incorrectly

Tags: ajax, jsf, omnifaces

I'm using the Omnifaces ajax.oncomplete function to show a toastr message in my JSF 2 page. The problem I'm facing is that I'm developping a frensh web application and we use a lot of quotes ('). When I add the quote, the browser throws a malformed XML exception :

```
malformedXML: missing ) after argument list
```

While I'm using the braqueted slash to make it ignore the quote and treat it as a string :

```
Ajax.oncomplete("toastr.warning('Vérifier l\'adresse e-mail saisie.')");
```

Is there a way to pass this exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` is also an escape character in Java itself. So, ultimately the `\` got stripped off by Java.

You need to double-escape it to represent a literal `\`, so it arrives as a real `\` in JavaScript.

```
Ajax.oncomplete("toastr.warning('Vérifier l\\'adresse e-mail saisie.')");
```

Alternatively, if those strings are not hardcoded and thus coming from a dynamic source, and you'd basically thus need to perform automatic escaping, then better use `Ajax#data()` to automatically let OmniFaces encode the Java variable as a properly formatted JSON object available via `OmniFaces.Ajax.data` in JavaScript context.

```
Ajax.data("message", "Vérifier l'adresse e-mail saisie.");
Ajax.oncomplete("toastr.warning(OmniFaces.Ajax.data.message)");
```

This way you don't need to worry about escaping fuss.